# Using multiple logical "or" operators

Tags: javascript, logic, control-flow

Other than using a switch statement (or writing `if(x === 2 || x === 3 || x === 4)` etc), is there any way to implement multiple "or" (`||`) operators?

E.g.:

```
if(x === 2 || 3)
    alert("Yes");
```

This alerts for every value of x

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov JavaScript (added tag to question)

Comment: @cloudcoder2000 That doesn't really answer my question - I was wondering if there was a short hand for the repetitive `if(x === "a" || x === "b" || etc...)`

Comment: @user2521439 Sorry, I didn't really read the question properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest you can probably come is to do something like this:

```
if ([2,3].indexOf(x) > -1){
}
```

[DOCS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Of course that will require a shim for IE 8 and below, if that's an issue for you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response which works for this occasion but wondered if there was any general syntax

Comment: +1. @user2521439 - no, there is no language construct in JavaScript for multiple matches (`switch` is one as you've said, but it usually takes too much space). Functional languages (F#, Haskell,...) do have such language constructs for matching.

Answer (score 2):

Standard approach for large number of choices is to use dictionary/hash set/hash table depending on language.

For JavaScript both array and object would work:

```
var isPresent = [];  
isPresent[2] = true;
isPresent[43] = true;
if (isPresent[x])...
```

For small number of items Adam Rackis' answer with linear search is much more readable

```
 [2,3].indexOf(x)
```